# What exactly has to be done on a SharePoint 2013 Installation to allow F5 - debugging for provider hosted AddIns?

Tags: authentication, provider-hosted-app, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have a provider hosted App I want to (F5)-Debug directly on a SharePoint 2013 Installation on a different server.

The Admins asked me what has to be done on the farm so they can decide if it even is ok to allow that and what exactly has to be done.

We have already the possiblity to install a provider-hosted app. I send them the app-package and the server-(MVC)-appliation and they install it. Everything for that need is already configured and works.

Now I need to be able to "just" press F5 in my Visual Studio and start that app.  On my **local installation** I simply set up the correct value in the "Site URL" property of the App. 
The same works when deploying to Office365: Enter the correct URL there, press F5 and debugging starts.

There are a lot of documentations to get everything up and running, but I cannot find any infos on what has to be done to simply just allow that debugging for an on premise-installation. Are there any additional features that have to be enabled on the farm so the SharePoint trusts my local IIS where the MVC-Application is running? Any ports that need to be opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug the SharePoint Provider Hosted app in on premises environment , Server to Server Trust configuration need to be done . here this can be achieved by registering a digital certificate as SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer in server and using the .pfx file of the same certificate file while developing the provider hosted app in the local machine.

Please refer below article for more info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179901.aspx